# send text message from PC to Mobile via bluetooth in C#

Tags: c#, bluetooth

I want to send text   message from PC to Mobile via bluetooth and I wrote this code

```
private void send_text()
    { BluetoothRadio.PrimaryRadio.Mode = RadioMode.Discoverable;
        bluetoothClient = new BluetoothClient();

    for (int i = 0; i < sayi; i++)
    {                        
            InTheHand.Net.BluetoothAddress adres = this.adres_dizisi[i];
            try
            {
                bluetoothClient.Connect(new BluetoothEndPoint((BluetoothAddress)adres,service));
                // in this line error
                // socketexception was found   The requested address is not valid in its context InTheHand.Net.BluetoothEndPoint


                System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream straem = bluetoothClient.GetStream();
                StreamWriter steramWriter = new StreamWriter(straem);

                steramWriter.WriteLine("! 0 200 200 210 1");

                // more stuff here.
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

What can I do to solve this problem?..Please help me..

Comment: Have you checked the contents of **adres_dizisi**? Does it contain your receiver's bluetooth device address?

Comment: I checked and yes it contains.

Comment: What service are you using in your connect method?