# Send any text message from PC to mobile via Bluetooth in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to send text message from System to any mobile phone by Bluetooth coonection but I am not able to send it.

I have also take help for this link but this code generate errors 
  [send text message from PC to Mobile via bluetooth in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7398842/send-text-message-from-pc-to-mobile-)  via-bluetooth-in-c-sharp.

```
public async Task<bool> Send(Device device, string content)
        {
            if (device == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("device");
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(content))
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("content");
            }

        // for not block the UI it will run in a different threat
            var task = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                using (var bluetoothClient = new BluetoothClient())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var ep = new       BluetoothEndPoint(device.DeviceInfo.DeviceAddress, _serviceClassId);

                    // connecting
                        bluetoothClient.Connect(ep);

                        // get stream for send the data
                        var bluetoothStream = bluetoothClient.GetStream();

                    // if all is ok to send
                        if (bluetoothClient.Connected && bluetoothStream != null)
                        {
                        // write the data in the stream
                            var buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content);
                            bluetoothStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                            bluetoothStream.Flush();
                            bluetoothStream.Close();
                            return true;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                    // the error will be ignored and the send data will report as not sent
                    // for understood the type of the error, handle the exception
                    }
                }
                 return false;
            });
            return await task;
        }
    }
```

Comment: it would be good if you could post what have you done in here and post ur codes

Comment: If by "sending text message" you mean a SMS, then it can't be done via bluetooth (or at least, there's no -generic- way). If you mean "send a text stream over a bluetooth serial communication socket", then if you want help you need to show what you have tried and where is the error. Stack Overflow is not here to make the code for you.

Comment: I have post a code that we have been used to send text message , Please check it

Comment: Would you clarify what the problem is with this code? At present we understand it does not do what you expect - do you get any errors? Are there any logs you think we should see? How do you know it is not working?